# How to convert UTF-8 URDU text to image on the fly in Php?

Tags: php, image, utf-8, on-the-fly, urdu

**اردو کے فونٹ کے مسائل**

میرے ویب پیچ کے فونٹ ، براوزر کی وجہ سے بدل جاتے ہیں، میں  اپنے صفحے کو امیج 
بنا کر براوزر کو دینا چایتا ہوں۔

I have tried a number of tutorials / examples  and searches.  I could not find solution.

- **A Tip: ( Hope it will make someone's life easier.)**

A big trouble , I resolved in image creation was use of Windows Share-Point to save my .php files. All files i was saving ,  had something UTF BOM .

When I saved same file using  simple Notepad in UTF-8 encoding , my image creation in PHP started.

- **My Problem.**

I have a sentence in URDU ( a language Spoken by a billion in South Asia ), say a string - saved in UTF-8 , perfectly being saved in database and on shown at web browsers.

Unlike English, Urdu letters join to make words, While joining , their apparent shape is cropped  - size or style.

I am working on this code

```
<?php
function watermarkImage ($SourceFile, $WaterMarkText, $DestinationFile) { 
    //$SourceFile is source of the image file to be watermarked
    //$WaterMarkText is the text of the watermark
    //$DestinationFile is the destination location where the watermarked images will be placed
    //Delete if destinaton file already exists
    @unlink($DestinationFile);

    //This is the vertical center of the image
    $top = getimagesize($SourceFile);
    $top = $top[1]/2;
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($SourceFile);

    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($SourceFile);

    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height); 

    //Path to the font file on the server. Do not miss to upload the font file
    $font = 'arial.ttf';

    //Font sie
    $font_size = 36; 

    //Give a white shadow
    $white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 155);   
    imagettftext($image_p, $font_size, 0, 10, $top, $white, $font, $WaterMarkText);

    //Print in black color
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0);
    imagettftext($image_p, $font_size, 0, 8, $top-1, $black, $font, $WaterMarkText);

   if ($DestinationFile<>'') {

      imagejpeg ($image_p, $DestinationFile, 100); 

   } else {

      header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

      imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);

   };

   imagedestroy($image); 

   imagedestroy($image_p); 

};

?>

<?php
/*
// The text to draw
    require('../../../I18N/Arabic.php');   //  It converts the  left side language to right side 
    $Arabic = new I18N_Arabic('Glyphs');  // 
    $font = './DroidNaskh-Bold.ttf';
$text = "جب درخشاں ہوں ستاروں کے چراغ";

$text =  $Arabic->utf8Glyphs('جب درخشاں ہوں ستاروں کے چراغ ');
It gave me   ﻍﺍﺭچ ےک ںﻭﺭﺎﺘﺳںﻭہ ںﺎﺸﺧﺭﺩ ﺐﺟ    ,  reversing the string ,  
*/

 $text = "ﻍﺍﺭچ ےک ںﻭﺭﺎﺘﺳںﻭہ ںﺎﺸﺧﺭﺩ ﺐﺟ";   // Problem in joining of Urdu - 

// Text
// Sequence  of characters reversed in string using utf8Glyphs(  ) ; 

$SourceFile = 'nature  (28).jpg';//Source image
$DestinationFile = 'watermarked/sky.jpg';//Destination path 
//Call the function to watermark the image
watermarkImage ($SourceFile, $text, $DestinationFile);

//Display watermarked image if desired
if(file_exists($DestinationFile)){
    echo "<img src=\"watermarked/sky.jpg\">";
    echo "<p>The image has been watermarked at '".$DestinationFile."'</p>";
}
?>
```

My image creation on the FLY for other then UTF-8 is working fine.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an additional library to perform Arabic glyph joining. Check out AR-PHP.

Comment: Dear Asif, AOA.  I have tried a lot,  Few words do not join as required in Urdu.

Comment: yep same issue 'm facing , if you solved it please share it  @wasif

Comment: did you get any solution, i am in the same problem

Comment: guys any solution found so far? having same issue

Comment: No solution found so far. improved the code, solution updated, and the reverse of the string also

Comment: No solution found so far. improved the code, solution updated, and the reverse of the string also

Answer (score 0):

For URDU text to Image, No solution was found, in PhP,  no library worked, and no Arabic or Persian library helped.
Finally, I opted for a Work Around.     Use HTML5 CANVAS, with a few lines of JS and et the text converted to images.

With slit modifications,  my previous code got to this stage,  I tried even changing ISO-8859-1, and tried to use it after I Convert UTF-8 string to HTML entities

```
`<?php
 function watermarkImage ($SourceFile, $WaterMarkText, $reverseText, $basicText,  
 $DestinationFile , $Text, $Text7,$Text8) { 
 //$SourceFile is the source of the image file to be watermarked
 //$WaterMarkText is the text of the watermark
 //$DestinationFile is the destination location where the watermarked images will be placed
 //Delete if destinaton file already exists
 @unlink($DestinationFile);
 //This is the vertical center of the image
 $top = getimagesize($SourceFile);
 $top = $top[1]/2;
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize($SourceFile);
 $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
 $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($SourceFile);
 imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height); 
 //Path to the font file on the server. Do not miss to upload the font file
 $font = 'C:/Windows/Fonts/Jameel Noori Nastaleeq.ttf';
 //Font sie
 $font_size = 22; // `

`//Give a white shadow
 $white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 155);   
 imagettftext($image_p, $font_size, 0, 10, $top, $white, $font, $WaterMarkText);

 //Print in black color
 $black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0);
 imagettftext($image_p, $font_size, 0, 8, 33, $black, $font, $WaterMarkText);   
 imagettftext($image_p, $font_size, 0, 68, 120, $black, $font,  $reverseText);
 imagettftext($image_p, $font_size, 0, 100, 190, $black, $font,  $basicText);
 imagettftext($image_p, $font_size, 0, 8, $top, $black, $font, $Text);  
 imagettftext($image_p, $font_size, 0, 8, $top+62, $black, $font, $Text7);  
 imagettftext($image_p, $font_size, 0, 8, $top+120, $black, $font, $Text8); 
 if ($DestinationFile<>'') {
  imagejpeg ($image_p, $DestinationFile, 100); 
 } else {
   header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
  };

   imagedestroy($image); 

   imagedestroy($image_p); 

   };




  $text7 = "کر سکتی ہے بے معرکہ جِینے کی تلافی";   // Problem in joining of Urdu - 


 // Convert UTF-8 string to HTML entities
 $text = mb_convert_encoding($text7, 'HTML-ENTITIES',"UTF-8");
 // Convert HTML entities into ISO-8859-1
 $text8 = html_entity_decode($text,ENT_NOQUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
 // Convert characters > 127 into their hexidecimal equivalents
 $out = "";
 for($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {
 $letter = $text[$i];
 $num = ord($letter);
 if($num>127) {
 $out .= "&#$num;";
 } else {
 $out .=  $letter;
 }
 }

  $my_string5 = $my_string6 = "";   
  function ReverseText ($my_string , $my_string7 ) { 
  $len6  = strlen($my_string);
  $my_array = preg_split('//', $my_string , -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 
  for ($x = 0; $x < $len6 ; $x++) {
    $yy = $x +1;    $y = $len6 -$yy;  
    $my_string7 .= $my_array [$y] ; 
  }
  return $my_string7; 
  }; 

$reverseText =  ReverseText ($text , $my_string5 ); 

$basicText =  ReverseText ($reverseText , $my_string6 );  
// Text
// Sequence  of characters reversed in string using utf8Glyphs(  ) ; 

 $SourceFile = 'bb.jpg';//Source image
 $DestinationFile = 'book.jpg';//Destination path 
 //Call the function to watermark the image
 watermarkImage ($SourceFile, $text, $reverseText, $basicText,  $DestinationFile, $text , $text7 , $text8);

 //Display watermarked image if desired
 if(file_exists($DestinationFile)){
 echo "<img src=\"book.jpg\">";
 echo "<p>The image has been watermarked at '".$DestinationFile."'</p>"; 
 }
 ?>
```

`

Simple HTML5 solution using Canvas

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="522" height="80" style="display:none;">
</canvas>
<img id="canvasImg" alt="Right click to save me!">
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

 context.font = "40px Jameel Noori Nastaleeq";
 context.fillText("فکر رہتی تھی مجھے جس کی وہ محفل ہے یہی ", 50, 60);


  // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

  // set canvasImg image src to dataURL
  // so it can be saved as an image
  document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;

 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Best solution** and I close the quest

**Use PHP, HTML5 Canvas, and JS to convert UTF- Urdu text to image**

My PHP code  calls a simple function for  re-using  many times in same page

```
echo generateCanvas($newCanvas, 'second', $textColor, $second , '2px', '8px'  , $cWIDTH );
```

And Function I made

```
function generateCanvas($myCanvas, $className, $textColor , $misra , $cLEFT,  $cTOP ,$cWIDTH ) {
  $output = "";
  $output .= "<span class=\"$className\">\n";  
  $output .= "<canvas id=\"$myCanvas\"  style='position: relative;   left: $cLEFT; top: $cTOP;  '  width='$cWIDTH' height='65'> ";
  $output .= "</canvas>\n";
  $output .= "<script>\n";
  $output .= "var canvas = document.getElementById('$myCanvas');\n";
  $output .= "canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';\n";
  $output .= "var cty = canvas.getContext('2d');\n";
  $output .= "cty.font = '28px Jameel Noori Nastaleeq';\n";
  $output .= "cty.fillStyle = '$textColor';\n";
  $output .= "cty.fillText('$misra', 530, 50);\n";
  $output .= "</script>\n";
  $output .= "</span>\n";
  return $output;
}
```

I also added in my CSS file code to call font from my website,  for local host, the code to add these lines

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Jameel Noori Nastaleeq';
  src: url('http://localhost/fonts/Jameel%20Noori%20Nastaleeq.ttf') format('truetype');
 
}
```

[image]

few more ,  [image]

**In short the solution is:**

```
<canvas id="firstCanvas8"  style='position: relative;   left: 2; top: 2;  '  width='548' height='65'> </canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('firstCanvas8');
var cty = canvas.getContext('2d');
cty.font = '28px Jameel Noori Nastaleeq';
cty.fillStyle = 'red';
cty.fillText('سارے جہاں سے اچھا ہندوستاں ہمارا ', 530, 50);
</script>
```

[image]